# WPF - How to fill the window with squares

Tags: c#, wpf

Hey guys so I have a wpf application and I want to make a 100x100 grid of squares and be able to treat it like a normal collection (List, Array etc) in my code ;

How could I do that in WPF without writing `<Rectangle .../>` 10,000 times?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use a `WrapPanel` combined with an `ItemsControl` to do that :

```
<ItemsControl x:Name="RectanglesItemsControl">
    <ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
       <ItemsPanelTemplate>
           <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True"/>
       </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
         <DataTemplate DataType="myNamespace:MyType">
             <Rectangle Width="{Binding Width}" Height="{Binding Height}"/>
         </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

MyType would be a simple class with a `Width` and `Height` property, it would also need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

You can then set your `ItemsControl`'s `ItemsSource` to your List, or even better, an `ObservableCollection<MyType>`, to register the collection changes:

```
RectangleItemsControl.ItemsSource = myLongCollectionFilledWithALotOfRectangles;
```

EDIT: You can replace `WrapPanel` by anything you want, you can also use a `<UniformGrid Rows="100" Columns="100" IsItemsHost="True"/>` to have 100 rows and columns.

Comment: to make the `WrapGrid` 100x100, you also need to set some properties.

Comment: Yes, you can also use `UniformGrid` to acheive that. I will edit that